# awk -F not finding strings if AND condition is used

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, solaris

I need to print second part of the searched string

```
a="Hello I have a CREATE set TABLE as (uid, cid, mid)"
```

Above string may continue as long as it needs.

```
echo "$a" | awk -F"/CREATE/&&/TABLE/" '{print $2}'
```

> it returns nothing...

It should return:

> as (uid, cid,mid)

Comment: How can you have a field separator that is `CREATE` and also is `TABLE`? That makes no sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "$a" | awk -F"CREATE.*TABLE" '{print $2}'
 as (uid, cid, mid)
```

Not sure if regex in Field Separator do work.

---

Using variable Field Separators:

```
sep=two
echo "_one_two_three_four" | awk -v var=$sep '{split($0,a,"_"var);print a[2]}'
_three_four
```

```
sep=three
echo "_one_two_three_four" | awk -v var=$sep '{split($0,a,"_"var);print a[2]}'
_four
```

Comment: is . field separator ?

Comment: can i use any variables in search string such as `awk -F"CREATE.*$string" '{print $2}'`

Comment: @logan I have not seen that used.  But you can use `split` instead of `FS` like this: `awk -v var=$string '{split($0,a,"CREATE.*"var);print a[2]}'`

Comment: @logan see my updated post showing variable divisor.

Comment: `awk -F"CREATE.*$string" '{print $2}'` is working for me in linux; will it cause any issue in solaris ?

Comment: @logan I do see this way also works on my `gnu awk`, but for solaris I do not know.  `split` will work on solaris.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49676/discussion-between-logan-and-jotne)

Comment: If one of the search key word is repeated in variable, then it is taking last matched key pattern. But I want the first matched pattern